# MySQL - WHERE IN() - get all data

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

I am having this query:
`SELECT * FROM data WHERE ID IN(1,2,3);`

I would like to know if there is any possibility to change an IN argument value to get all rows in the table. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE ID IN(LIKE %%);
SELECT * FROM data WHERE ID IN(ANY);
SELECT * FROM data WHERE ID IN(ALL);
etc.
```

I know that all I have to do is just remove "WHERE ID IN(..)" to get what I need but this is more theoretical question.

Comment: Reason is that my app has a function that return array of allowed ID's that can currently logged in user see. But if the user is an administrator, he can see all ID's. Currently the app returns an array with value 'range(1, 9999)' which is so bad. This data are then used in mysql query.

Comment: skip the id part in the where clause and omly search for active users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think about next approach:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE ID IN(SELECT ID FROM data);
```

It's stuppid, but answer the question :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't have `in` do what you want. I would recommend having a second parameter to your query, that indicates whether the current user is admin or not. You can then pass a boolean value to this parameter (either `0` or `1`):

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE ID IN(%s) OR %s;
                 -- is admin (0 or 1) ^
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try reverse of your query.

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE ID not IN(-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, this is my solution. This way must be used only in `char` columns:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE ID IN(false);
```